# What's the best way to create this formula with latex?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I'm trying to create this formula (the one with the matrices) for my essay in latex but I'm having a hard time finding the best way of going about it.

[image: matrix formula]

Comment: `pmatrix` env for the patrices and vectores, `\dots`, `\vdots`, `\ddots` for the dots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coding of this matrix product is quite straightforward, just take the time to write the four matrices that make up the formula with indexed variables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
%>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    y_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    y_n
  \end{pmatrix}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & x_{12} & \ldots & x_{1k} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & x_{N2} & \ldots & x_{Nk}
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \beta_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    \beta_k
  \end{pmatrix}
  +
  \begin{pmatrix}
    u_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    u_k
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\end{document}
```

[image: produit matriciel]

Comment: Oops, the top right element in the second matrix should be `x_{1k}`.

Comment: @barbara beeton: It was a deliberate mistake to see if the participants in tex.stackechange had the sagacity attributed to them :-). I'm glad to see it's real. I will now be able to use the good advice I find on this site with confidence. Big thanks  ! (I corrected the error)

Comment: There are too many unnecessary yet distracting `%`.

Comment: @gigiair -- I may not be a good example for this purpose.  Although quite a few participants here are long-time TeX users and package developers, and we try to be both helpful and truthful, we're not the "whole story".  Just be careful, please.

Comment: @vtfs271232 -- While it's true that none of the `%` signs in this example are needed, it would have been helpful to give the reason -- spaces are ignored in math.  The trick about using `%` signs is to learn where they are necessary or useful, and where they can be ignored.  And that does take practice.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I agree. Thank you!

Comment: @all: As I used Emacs Calc to produce the LaTeX code, the expression `{1k}` is simplified to `k` and has to be corrected manually. It was not really a good idea to present to a beginner. I removed controversial parts of my post.